# How does Firebase know which country the user is from?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In Firebase console there is a cloud messaging option for sending notification to mobile users directly (not via api).

Inside there is an option to segment the users you want to send the message to by country.

[image]

Ive tested the feature by targeting one specific country but notifications were sent to some people from other countries also.

My question is how does Firebase calculate/infer which country is the user from?

Comment: Using ip address

Comment: If it is the ip address it would be good to know how its used. A scenario where user travels to six different countries and uses the app. Does that mean he will belong to all of those countries when i send out a notification by country?

Comment: Did anyone found any reference to this yet? If my user moves to a different country firebase continue to hold the last country/region for them. ideally they should update it